# Can Chrome and Safari access two different ports from the same page?

Tags: websocket, https

Currently my browser based application connects via port 7000 for both https web pages and websockets communication.

I understand that for security reasons, the browser will not let you connect to different IP addresses at the same time within the page.

My question is can my web page access the server (https port 443) for web page acquisition and then within the page open a https/wss.websocket connection to a different port (assuming the server is setup to accept a connection on that different port)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES.

I was hoping to get an answer so I would not have to design a test - but I did - and I can connect with WS on a different port than the port used to acquire web pages.